# Why don't I need to use invlpg on QEMU after changing paging structure?

Tags: c, kernel, paging, mmu, tlb

Im writing a kernel from scratch and am curious... why is it that when I change something in my page directory QEMU immediately recognizes the change without having to flush the TLB? Here is my code:

(I have paging enabled and the first 4MB are identity mapped, and my kernel is mapped in PDE #768 for higher half mode.)

```
...
register_int_handler(14, &page_fault); //Setup my page fault handler
//We are in the higher half so we unmap PDE 0 since we don't need it anymore
uint32_t *pd = (uint32_t *)0xFFFFF000; //Get PD
pd[0] = 0x00000002; //Supervisor, R/W, Not Present

uint32_t *cause_fault = (uint32_t *)0x00001000; //Any old unmapped page here
//Call to invlpg here?
*cause_fault = 5; //Causes the page fault

print("Hello world!");
...
```

The above code causes ISR 14 (page fault) to be fired. It is my understanding that after altering a paging structure, the TLB needs to be updated with a call to `invlpg`. Is this correct? Why does the page fault still happen in QEMU without calling `invlpg`? Is it because QEMU's TLB is emulated a weird way that is different from real hardware or what? Any insight would be great.

Comment: The same thing occurs on VirtualBox.